# Why HTMLParser ignores start tags in non-strict mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing

I wrote a simple parser based on HTMLParser:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, strict = True):
        super().__init__(strict)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print('Start tag: ', tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print('End tag ', tag)
```

Then I try to parse the next example in strict and non-strict mode (by passing strict=True or strict=False in HTMLParser constructor):

```
source = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello HTML</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </body>
</html>
'''
#myParser = MyParser(True) # strict
myParser = MyParser(False) # non-strict
myParser.feed(source)
myParser.close()
```

As a result, I got two different result for strict and non-strict modes.
strict:

```
Start tag:  html
Start tag:  head
Start tag:  title
End tag  title
End tag  head
Start tag:  body
Start tag:  p
End tag  p
End tag  body
End tag  html
```

non-strict:

```
End tag  title
End tag  head
End tag  p
End tag  body
End tag  html
```

Why HTMLParser ignores start tags in non-strict mode? How to use HTMLParser in non-strict mode with no omitting of start tags?

Comment: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) likes variables named `my_parser` instead of `myParser`.

Comment: Can't reproduce this (3.2.3, Ubuntu 64-bit).

Comment: It's possible that it's a bug that has been fixed in 3.2.3, but I think it's more likely that it was user error. Try doing it again.

Comment: I can reproduce this with Python 3.2.2, looks like this bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue13273

Comment: Fixed by upgrading to 3.2.3 version. Thanks a lot to you all for quick help.

Comment: @ch3ka: how about you put an answer to that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in python 3.2.2 (and other), see http://bugs.python.org/issue13273 for details and a quickfix. It is fixed in 3.2.3.